# 'DHT11' was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino

```
#include "DHT.h" 
#include <Arduino.h>
#define DHTPIN D1
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define LED  D4
#define LED2 D8
#define LED3 D7

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
dht.begin();
pinMode (LED,  OUTPUT);
pinMode (LED2, OUTPUT);
pinMode (LED3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
Serial.println("prende led");
digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
Serial.println("apaga led");
}
```

Aunque estoy importando la librería "DHT.h" no me reconoce el tipo "DHT11"
Alguien sabe que pasa?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si quitas `#include <Arduino.h>` q sucede?

Comment: Sigue teniendo el mismo problema, estoy pensando que quizá pueda ser algun cruce extraño de librerias, por que lo intenté compilar con uno de los ejemplos de la libreria DHT y daba el mismo problema, y ensayé el mismo ejemplo en otro computador y lo compiló sin problemas... me deja desconcertado entonces cual es la causa del error

Comment: Tienes la ultima version del Arduino IDE?

Comment: Si, fue lo primero que verifiqué y volví a bajar e instalar el IDE y tampoco es eso al parecer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Había un problema entre librerias, estaba usando la libreria por defecto de DHT la que se encuentra en la ruta "/Documents/Arduino/libreries" eso en mi caso, para otro revisar la ruta en donde están las librerias, tal parece que para el sensor DHT11 lo reconoces es la libreria de adafruit la se puede bajar en esta direccion https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library y recuerden que esa libreria tambien requiere de esta que pueden bajar de acá https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Sensor, para solucionar el problema lo que hice fue eliminar la libreria de DHT y dejar solo las de Adafruit y listo, compiló perfectamente.